# removing trailing slashes in django rest framework in all urls: added with router, manually or using include

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-rest-auth

I'm building an API using Django REST frameworks and would like to get rid of all the trailing slashes in all the urls.
I did add `APPEND_SLASH = False` in `settings.py`

Here are the different cases I encountered:

1. Explicit urls:
   No problem since we can control the regex fully:

`urlpatterns = [...,url(r'^api/objects/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/property$', SomeView.as_view(), name='object-property'),...]`

Which allows to send requests to `/api/objects/1/property`

2. Using a router:

`router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)`

`router.register(r'some-endpoint',SomeViewSet,base_name='some_endpoint')`

`url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),`

Which allows to send requests to `/api/some-endpoint`

3. **Problem:** Using third-party packages

For instance I'm trying to use django-rest-auth. I have installed it with pip and, following the docs I added the urls I need (including registration) to `urlpatterns` like so:

`url(r'^api/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
url(r'^api/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>[-:\w]+)/$', ConfirmEmailView.as_view(), name='account_confirm_email'),
url(r'^api/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),`

this will make, for instance, the endpoint `/api/login/` active but WITH a trailing slash which I don't want for consistency.

I then tried to remove `url(r'^api/', include('rest_auth.urls'))` and, focusing on the `login` endpoint, imported its view:

`from rest_auth.views import LoginView`

and added the url to `urlpatterns` hoping to be able to use it without the trailing slash:

`url(r'^api/login$', LoginView.as_view(), name='rest_login'),`

or

`url(r'^api/login', LoginView.as_view(), name='rest_login'),`

None of these worked.

However if I add the trailing slash:
`url(r'^api/login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='rest_login')`

the endpoint will work.

4. **Minor Problem:** For the admin site

I have a similar issue with the admin site which is added with:

`url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),`

all the endpoints have trailing_slashes including `/admin/`

while:
    `url(r'^api/docs', include_docs_urls(title='API Doc',public=False))`

will add the docs without any trailing slashes anywhere.

So how can I remove the trailing slashes for:
- django-rest-auth or any other third party package?
- for the admin website?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Are you using a web server in front of your application - such as nginx or Apache? These can be configured to automatically add a trailing slash to requests that don't have them.

Comment: I would rather deal with that in the django project and want to remove trailing slash not add them